# Mysterious "remove" key inserted in my object when populating it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I am iterating over an array(results) and populating an object(testArray). Here's my code for this:

```
$.each(results, function(key, value)
{
        console.log('value is');
        console.log(value.Id);
        testArray[value.Id] = value;
});
for(var key in testArray) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(testArray[key].Name);
        }
```

**The problem:** When iterating over testArray the last key printed is "remove" and the name associated with it is "undefined". Such a value.Id as "remove" does not exist is never printed from the $.each.

Comment: you probably have another library adding a remove method to Array.prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if it's an object, not an array (your code names it `testArray` which is really confusing), then you can do this to eliminate enumerable properties that have been added to the prototype:

```
for (var key in testArray) {
    if (testArray.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(testArray[key]);
    }
}
```

---

Previous answer when we all though `testArray` was an array.

This is exactly why you should never be iterating an array with:

```
for (var key in testArray)
```

because that iterates all enumerable properties of the array object, not only array elements.  You are probably running some code that adds a new method do the array object that is being picked up by your `for/in` iteration.

Instead use a traditional `for` loop or use `.forEach()`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(testArray[i]);
}
```

or

```
testArray.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

These methods will enumerate only actual array elements, not other properties that may have been added to the Array object.

P.S. It's possible to add methods to an Array that will not suffer this problem if they are made non-enumerable, but you should still not ever be iterating an array with `for/in`.  Also, ES6 has a new `for/of` syntax that can be used safely to iterate arrays, but it requires an ES6 environment.

Comment: I suspected something like what you mentioned happened. However since testArray is an object I cannot use .length on it. I tried that. Your other suggestion .forEach doesn't work either. I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Arthlete - You didn't say it was a plain object and your code calls it `testArray` so we all assumed it was an array.  That's a bad variable name if it's not an array.  See what I added to the start of my answer.

Comment: you are correct. I was in a hurry when writing the code. It's my bad. Thanks for the help!